# Failed to download url

Tags: ios, swift

Okay, so basically I'm creating a messenger app which I want to be able to upload and load a profile picture. Currently I can successfully upload a picture to firebase, but as stated in the title, it fails to download the picture URL.

(Tutorial that I am watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hmr8PsG9E2w&list=PL5PR3UyfTWvdlk-Qi-dPtJmjTj-2YIMMf&index=18&ab_channel=iOSAcademy) 15-20 min into the video.

Where the error occurs:

```
strongSelf.storage.child("images/"+fileName).downloadURL(completion: {url, error in
            guard let url = url else {
                print("Failed to get download url")
                completion(.failure(StorageErrors.failedToGetDownloadUrl))
                return
            }
```

- 

```
   let safeEmail = DatabaseManager.safeEmail(emailAddress: email)
            let filename = safeEmail + "_profile_picture.png"
            let path = "images/"+filename
```

[Error message in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4bNVK.png)

What I've tried:

- Changing and double checking that the path leads to the picture.
- Trying different tactics of calling path like ("(path)") instead of (path)
- Other random stuff that I found looking for this problem on the web

What my conclusion so far is that the program does not seem to indentify the correct path to the picture, but I've made sure that it looks identical to the video.

Would be awesome if anyone knows or has any idea how to deal with this issue? This is my first post so please tell me if more information is needed regarding the code is needed.

Cheers // Jakob

Adding extra to comments:

So the (error) is : failedToGetDownloadUrl

So this is where I suspect there is something going wrong:

```
   strongSelf.storage.child("images/\(fileName)").downloadURL(completion: { url, error in
                guard let url = url else {
                    print("Failed to get download url")
                    completion(.failure(StorageErrors.failedToGetDownloadUrl))
                    return
                }

                let urlString = url.absoluteString
                print("download url returned: \(urlString)")
                completion(.success(urlString))
            })
        })
    }
```

And here are the Path to the images:

```
let safeEmail = DatabaseManager.safeEmail(emailAddress: email)
        let filename = safeEmail + "_profile_picture.png"
        let path = "images"+filename
```

And this is my firebase storage:
[image: Firebase Storage]

Comment: Your should print the actual error object (`print(error)`) so that you know what the error is telling you. Also, please show the actual path to the item as you see it in the Firebase console and then show what `"images/" + fileName` results in.

Comment: "the program does not seem to indentify the correct path to the picture"  What is the correct path, then?

Comment: Hello guys! Thanks for the help! I've been really busy with work and trying to solve this by myself. I think I fixed my answer so you might understand it a bit better.

Comment: @jnpdx, "images/" + fileName results in: images/joe-gmail-com_profile_picture.png

Comment: Have you tried printing the error yet?

Comment: Yes, the error is: failedToGetDownloadUrl